# Awk command for merging files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need an awk command to merge these two files that have matching values.

```
Color:Green
Color:Yellow 
Color:Orange
```

And

```
Green:Yes
Orange:Yes
```

And get

```
 Color:Green:Yes
 Color:Orange:Yes
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. It's better to be specific about what you are stuck on. (If you're asking us to just write it without you trying...that's not really what we're here for.)

Comment: Why do you need `AWK`? There might be a more suitable tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` and `sort` in `bash`:

```
$ join -t: -1 2  <( sort -t: -k2 colours.txt ) <( sort selected.txt )
Green:Color:Yes
Orange:Color:Yes
```

For correct ordering of fields:

```
$ join -t: -1 2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 <( sort -t: -k2 colours.txt ) <( sort selected.txt )
Color:Green:Yes
Color:Orange:Yes
```

`join` performs a relational JOIN operation on sorted input data.  In this case, the join field is the colour, which appears as the second `:`-delimited field in the first file and as the first `:`-delimited field in the second file.

With `join -t: -1 2` we make `join` pick the the second field from the first file as the "join key" field (the first field is the default) and with the two `<(...)` (process substitutions in `bash`) we provide the sorted data. The first `sort` is the only one that's "special" as it sorts the first file on its second `:`-delimited field, the colour.

The second example above uses the `-o` flag to explicitly specify what we'd like to see in the output and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]=$2; next} 
    ($2 in seen){print $0":"seen[$2]; next}1' file2  file1
```

Inputs:

> ```
> ==> file1 <==
> Color:Green
> Color:Yellow
> Color:Pinky
> Color:Orange
>
> ==> file2 <==
> Green:Yes
> Orange:Yes
> Yellow:No
> ```

Output:

> ```
> Color:Green:Yes
> Color:Yellow:No
> Color:Pinky
> Color:Orange:Yes
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming file1 is

```
color:green
color:yellow
color:orange
```

and file2 is

```
green:yes
orange:yes
```

I guess this will generate what you want:

```
awk -F ':' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){print a[$1]":"a[$2]} file2 file1
```

OUTPUT:

```
color:green:yes
color:orange:yes
```